# Filter out value from arrays within multiple objects using javascript and lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

In theory this sounds reasonably easy, but a certain AI bot keeps giving me incorrect info.
I have data that looks like this:

```
let newData = {
  '2020': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.5': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123', 'XYZ'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.75': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['XYZ'], Thing3: ['AAA'] }
};
```

All I want to do is remove values from the “Thing” arrays that are the same across all objects and specific array. In the case above remove ‘ABC’ and ‘123’ from the Thing1 arrays.
The returned data looking like this:

```
{
  '2020': { Thing1: [], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.5': { Thing1: ['XYZ'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.75': { Thing1: [], Thing2: ['XYZ'], Thing3: ['AAA'] }
}
```

This was the answer I got from the aforementioned AI bot:

```
const numObjects = Object.keys(newData).length;

_.forEach(newData, (value, key) => {
    _.forEach(value, (arr, thing) => {
        newData[key][thing] = _.filter(arr, (value) => {
            const count = _.countBy(newData, (obj) => obj[thing] && obj[thing].includes(value));
            return Object.keys(count).length !== numObjects;
        });
    });
});

console.log(newData);
```

But this just returns everything. I don’t think it’s iterating through the actual values in the Thing arrays.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author's code mutates the original object.
First we get counts of values, then we clean the arrays.

A pure solution by Damzaky is slower (but could be useful if we need to go pure).

You don't need the lodash here. The ES6+ allows to do the same things. I've added 2 lodash solutions to the benchmark but they are the slowest:

```
` Chrome/121
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nenashev's in-place solution            1.00x | x100000 124 127 132 133 136
Nenashev's pure solution                1.25x | x100000 155 160 161 162 167
Damzaky's pure solution                 2.23x | x100000 277 281 288 289 290
in-place lodash solution by 3limin4t0r  3.02x | x100000 374 376 387 394 402
lodash pure solution by Ori Drori       4.61x | x100000 572 580 589 590 599
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script name="benchmark" data-count="100000">

const getData = () => ({
    '2020': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
    '2020.5': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123', 'XYZ'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
    '2020.75': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['XYZ'], Thing3: ['AAA'] }
});

// @benchmark Nenashev's in-place solution
{
const newData = getData();

const values = Object.values(newData);

const mapped = values
    .reduce((map, item) =>
        Object.entries(item).forEach(
            ([key, arr]) => arr.forEach(value => {
                const values = map[key] ??= {};
                if (!values[value]) {
                    values[value] = 0;
                }
                values[value]++;
            })) || map, {});

values.forEach(item => {

    for (const key in item) {

        const arr = item[key];
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            mapped[key][arr[i]] === values.length &&
                arr.splice(i--, 1);
        }

    }

});

newData;

}
// @benchmark Nenashev's pure solution

{
    const newData = getData();

    const values = Object.values(newData);

    const mapped = values
        .reduce((map, item) =>
            Object.entries(item).forEach(
                ([key, arr]) => arr.forEach(value => {
                    const values = map[key] ??= {};
                    if (!values[value]) {
                        values[value] = 0;
                    }
                    values[value]++;
                })) || map, {});


    const result = {};
    for (const dataKey in newData) {

        const newItem = result[dataKey] = {};
        item = newData[dataKey];

        for (const key in item) {
            newItem[key] = item[key].filter(val=>mapped[key][val] !== values.length);
        }
    }

    result;

}

// @benchmark Damzaky's pure solution

{
const originalData = getData();

const mustRemove = Object.values(originalData).reduce((acc, val) => {
  let newAcc = { ...acc
  }
  Object.entries(val).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    newAcc[key] = key in newAcc ? value.filter(v => newAcc[key].includes(v)) : []
  })
  return newAcc
})

Object.entries(originalData).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: Object.entries(val).reduce((cacc, [ckey, cval]) => ({
    ...cacc,
    [ckey]: cval.filter(c => !mustRemove[ckey].includes(c))
  }), {})
}), {})
}

// @benchmark in-place lodash solution by 3limin4t0r
{
let newData = getData();

const rows = Object.values(newData);
const things = _.uniq(rows.flatMap((row) => (
  Object.keys(row).filter(key => key.match(/^Thing/))
)));

const intersections = Object.fromEntries(things.map((thing) => (
  [thing, _.intersection(...rows.map(row => row[thing] || []))]
)));

for (const row of rows) {
  for (const thing of things) {
    if (!(thing in row)) continue; // skip if key not present
    row[thing] = _.difference(row[thing], intersections[thing]);
  }
}

newData;

}

// @benchmark lodash pure solution by Ori Drori
{

const { mergeWith, cloneDeep, values, intersection, mapValues,  difference } = _;

const newData = getData();

const toRemove = mergeWith(
  ...cloneDeep(values(newData)), 
  (a, b) => intersection(a, b)
)

const result = mapValues(
  newData, 
  o => mapValues(o, (v, k) => difference(v, toRemove[k]))
)

result;


}

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for going to all the trouble of benchmarking. Really appreciate the effort you've put in. I've selected your In-Place solution purely because of the benchmark. Just a question, out of interest, why did you define the data in a getData function?

Comment: @Strontium_99 getData() is to not repeat the object literal in each benchmark (less code, DRY). we need to get a fresh object because we have 2 in-place benchmarks that mutate the object.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an object (`toRemove`) that contains, for each property, all the values that are common between the original objects.
2. Map the original object's values, and then map all the propertoes inside each object. Get the difference between each array, and it's `toRemove` counterpart property.

```js
const { mergeWith, clone, values, intersection, mapValues,  difference } = _;

const fn = obj => {
  const [first, ...rest] = values(newData);
  
  const toRemove = mergeWith(clone(first), ...rest, (a, b) => intersection(a, b));

  return mapValues(
    newData, 
    o => mapValues(o, (v, k) => difference(v, toRemove[k]))
  );
};

const newData = {"2020":{"Thing1":["ABC","123"],"Thing2":["DEF"]},"2020.5":{"Thing1":["ABC","123","XYZ"],"Thing2":["DEF"]},"2020.75":{"Thing1":["ABC","123"],"Thing2":["XYZ"],"Thing3":["AAA"]}};

const result = fn(newData);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i've added your solution to my answer (benchmark). i hope that's ok

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I've accepted Nenashev answer purely based on the bench test stats.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest solution. If for some reason speed is an issue, the easiest thing to change to speed this up is `cloneDeep(values(newData))`. `mergeWith` only mutes the first argument, so only the first argument has to be shallowly cloned. Replacing `cloneDeep(values(newData))` with `values(newData).map((value, i) => i ? value : clone(value))` or something alike, should make the code a bit faster.

Comment: @3limin4t0r - see updated example. We can avoid deep cloning the entire object using some destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but I would get the intersections of every "Thing" first, and then remove them from the "Thing"s:

```js
const originalData = {
  '2020': {
    Thing1: ['ABC', '123'],
    Thing2: ['DEF']
  },
  '2020.5': {
    Thing1: ['ABC', '123', 'XYZ'],
    Thing2: ['DEF']
  },
  '2020.75': {
    Thing1: ['ABC', '123'],
    Thing2: ['XYZ'],
    Thing3: ['AAA']
  }
};

const mustRemove = Object.values(originalData).reduce((acc, val) => {
  let newAcc = { ...acc
  }
  Object.entries(val).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    newAcc[key] = key in newAcc ? value.filter(v => newAcc[key].includes(v)) : []
  })
  return newAcc
})

const result = Object.entries(originalData).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: Object.entries(val).reduce((cacc, [ckey, cval]) => ({
    ...cacc,
    [ckey]: cval.filter(c => !mustRemove[ckey].includes(c))
  }), {})
}), {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wrong output, should be an object

Comment: You're right, fixed it

Comment: Great, added your solution to my answer and benmarked together with mine. I hope you are good with that. You have a pure one.

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I've accepted Nenashev answer purely based on the bench test stats.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to replace the data of `newData`, without a new object, a nested `for..of Object.keys()` and a `filter()` would be enough:

```js
const toRemove = [ 'ABC', '123' ];

let newData = {
  '2020': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.5': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123', 'XYZ'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.75': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['XYZ'], Thing3: ['AAA'] }
};

for (var o of Object.keys(newData)) {
    for (var key of Object.keys(newData[o])) {
        newData[o][key] = newData[o][key].filter(e => !toRemove.includes(e));
    }
}

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I've accepted Nenashev answer purely based on the bench test stats.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using mainly normal JavaScript. I do use `_.uniq`, `_.intersection` and `_.difference` since they don't have a simple JavaScipt equivalent.

This solution works in a few steps.

1. Collect all the `_.uniq` "Thing" keys.
2. Store an `_.intersection` of each "Thing" key.
3. Replace the "Thing" collection of each row with a new one. The new value is produced by taking the `_.difference` between the current value and the stored intersection.

```js
let newData = {
  '2020': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.5': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123', 'XYZ'], Thing2: ['DEF'] },
  '2020.75': { Thing1: ['ABC', '123'], Thing2: ['XYZ'], Thing3: ['AAA'] }
};

// we don't care aboute the `newData` labels, so take only the values
const rows = Object.values(newData);
// collect the different `Thing` keys
const things = _.uniq(rows.flatMap((row) => (
  Object.keys(row).filter(key => key.match(/^Thing/))
)));

// build an intersection array for each "Thing", use an empty array if the key is missing
const intersections = Object.fromEntries(things.map((thing) => (
  [thing, _.intersection(...rows.map(row => row[thing] || []))]
)));
console.log("intersections =", intersections);

// subtract the intersection from the row value (difference)
for (const row of rows) {
  for (const thing of things) {
    if (!(thing in row)) continue; // skip if key not present
    row[thing] = _.difference(row[thing], intersections[thing]);
  }
}

console.log("mutated newData =", newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Note that this answer mutates the original structure.

Comment: added your solution to my benchmark, i hope it's ok

Comment: Thank you for your post.  I've accepted Nenashev answer purely based on the bench test stats.